# duplicate values in dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

i have a dataframe like :

```
 doc_id       text                                       uci_class          tokens                                          lemma                                             pos
   1    accès rapide et facile personnel très avenant...    1        [accès, rapide, et, facile, , personnel, très...   [accès, rapide, et, facile, , personnel, très...    [NOUN, ADJ, CCONJ, VERB, SPACE, ADJ, ADV, VERB...
   2    les petits déjeuners sont les meilleurs que no...   1        [les, petits, déjeuners, sont, les, meilleurs,...  [le, petit, déjeuner, être, le, meilleur, que,...   [DET, ADJ, NOUN, AUX, DET, NOUN, PRON, PRON, A.
```

i want to have in output :

```
 doc_id       text                                       uci_class          tokens      lemma    pos
   1    accès rapide et facile personnel très avenant...    1                accès       accès   NOUN

   1    accès rapide et facile personnel très avenant...    1                rapide     rapide   ADJ

   1    accès rapide et facile personnel très avenant...    1                et            et   CCONJ
```

....

Comment: checkout `df.explode`

Comment: will need `df.join` as well @Ch3steR to avoid multiple products of the df by chaining `.explode` think its worthy of its own answer

Comment: @Manakin If list lengths are the same corresponding to each index then `df.apply(pd.Series.explode)` should do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a nice question, you can use df.explode function (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html?highlight=explode).

Use it like

```
df.explode('tokens')
df.explode('lemma')
df.explode('pos')
```